# Write Base64 encoded text node with libxml2

Tags: c++, c, xml, base64, libxml2

I have not found a proper tutorial on libxml2 yet and thus I'm struggling with some basic concepts, having "only" the [API docs](http://xmlsoft.org/html/index.html) at hand, which are, IMHO, a little too brief in some points.

This is (C++) my attempt to write Base64 encoded data to a document (a text node as a child of the root element):

```
// create doc and root node
xmlDocPtr doc = xmlNewDoc( (xmlChar*) "1.0" );
xmlNodePtr root_node = xmlNewNode( 0, (xmlChar*) "root" );
xmlDocSetRootElement( doc, root_node );

// create text node and write data
xmlNodePtr node = xmlNewDocText( doc, (xmlChar*) "" );
xmlAddChild( root_node, node );
xmlTextWriterPtr writer = xmlNewTextWriterTree( doc, node, 0 );
xmlTextWriterWriteBase64( writer, "asdf", 0, 4 );
```

The following is just doing test output:

```
// get textual representation
xmlChar *mem = 0;
int size = 0;
xmlDocDumpFormatMemory( doc, &mem, &size, 1 );
if ( mem ) {
    std::cout << mem << std::endl;
}
```

Unfortunately, the text node does not appear in the output.

I'd be thankful for a solution to this problem *and* some links to introductory material regarding libxml2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that xmlTextWriterWriteBase64() needs the context of where to put the text.  I was able to add the text to a new element via xmlTextWriterStartElement(), xmlTextWriterWriteBase64(), and xmlTextWriterEndElement().  You would think giving a node to xmlNewTextWriterTree() would set the context, but apparently it does not.  The "documentation" for libxml is just terrible (even the sample applications); they give you the how, but not the why.  I don't really know of any good documentation; I just figured most of it out by myself through trial and error (sad).

Comment: Hmm, I tried what you suggested and wrote `xmlTextWriterPtr writer = xmlNewTextWriterTree( doc, root_node, 0 );` `xmlTextWriterStartElement( writer, (xmlChar*) "node" );` `xmlTextWriterWriteBase64( writer, "asdf", 0, 4 );` `xmlTextWriterEndElement( writer );` but apparently this was not _exactly_ what you meant...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's exactly what I did.  One thing I forgot to mention was that I called xmlTextWriterFlush() prior to dumping the memory.

Comment: That did the trick, **thank you**. How on earth am I supposed to know that, I ask myself. Obviously, you have more experience in guessing these things than I have...

Comment: Another note: Calling `xmlFreeTextWriter()` flushed the buffer as well. In my case, this would have been the way to go.

Comment: Yeah, the libxml documentation is really lacking.  It was just a good guess on my part :)