# Base64 decode output of xmlNodeGetContent

Tags: c, base64, libxml2

I am slowly learning libxml2 API (version is 2.9.10) and I think I missing something obvious after a call to [`xmlNodeGetContent`](https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/libxml2/devhelp/libxml2-tree.html#xmlNodeGetContent).

I am getting the base64 data stored in the XML file using:

```
xmlChar *base64_data = xmlNodeGetContent(cur);
```

What API from libxml2 should I use to decode the base64 back to the original binary ? Grepping the source code, all I can find is [`xmlBase64Decode`](https://github.com/GNOME/libxml2/blob/v2.9.10/xmlreader.c#L5792) which does not seems to be exported.

Comment: Is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5475155/2115408) of any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libxml2 offers no API to decode base64. You have to do it manually or use another library.